# Bootstrap modal onclick before modal is run

Tags: jquery, onclick, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using a bootstap modal on my website, and i want to be able to set the text of the model while calling it

for this i planned to use the onclick function.

example:
when a user clicks the button "delete list" a modal pops up with the header that i set in that specific onclick function:

```
 function functionCalledByOnclick(){
   $("#modalHeader").html("<p>Are you sure you want to remove **?</p>");
```

however a button "save" could also be pressed, in wich case the header should say something different.

But when i click one of these buttons the modal is shown before the function is run and therefore the header text is not set.

Can i use the onclick function to set the text in a modal?
Or must i find another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JQuery it's easier to use the onclick event like this. This way you only need to assign an id to each button, and it's a bit easier on the eyes too.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var deleteText = "<p>Are you sure you want to remove **?</p>";
    var saveText = "<p>Do you want to save **?</p>";

    $("#deleteButton").click( function () {
        $("#modalHeader").html(deleteText);
        $("#modal").modal("show");
    });

    $("#saveButton").click( function () {
        $("#modalHeader").html(saveText);
        $("#modal").modal("show");
    });
});
```

You can of course shorten it down by erasing the variables, but this is more organised.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can set the text in a modal.

```
<script>

function functionCalledByOnclickDelete(){
  $("#modalname .modal-body p").text("Are you sure you want to remove **?");
  $('#modalname').modal('show');
}

function functionCalledByOnclickSave(){
  $("#modalname .modal-body p").text("Are you sure you want to save **?");
  $('#modalname').modal('show');
}

</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalname" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="simpleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>This text will be replaced after the function is called.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```